# Mermaid Links in new tab

Tags: github, gitlab, mermaid

How do I get a Mermaid Link in a Graph that opens in a new Tab? I already got the Link in the Node, but it opens in the same tab.

I tried the HTML synax, but those wouldn't work :D

Comment: According to [this issue](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/issues/3077), setting the `securityLevel` to `loose` would enable it.

Comment: Please share the HTML code so we can correct if need be.